# Using a struct and lists to store parts of a csv file

Tags: c#, csv

So I have to use a struct in this homework and we need to sort a CSV file called Countries_databas.csv So far I have made the struct and a list that will handle each split of one line on the CSV. However, I am struggling to add each split of the CSV into its respective list so I can sort them.

edit: Sorry, I have just realised I have missed the last split of on line of the CSV i.e "Kabul" on line one.

First 4 lines of my CSV:

```
1. Afghanistan,Asia,652230,25500100,20364000000,Kabul
2. Albania,Europe,28748,2821977,12044000000,Tirana
3. Algeria,Africa,2381741,38700000,207021000000,Algiers
4. Andorra,Europe,468,76098,3222000000,Andorra la Vella
```

The code:

```
namespace CSVFileUtility
{

  public struct CSVline
  {
    public List<string> Country;
    public List<string> Continent;
    public List<int> popualtion;
    public List<int> landmass;
    public List<long> Bignum;

    public CSVline(List<string> Country, List<string> Continent, List<int> popualtion, List<int> landmass, List<long> Bignum)
    {
      this.Country = Country;
      this.Continent = Continent;
      this.popualtion = popualtion;
      this.landmass = landmass;
      this.Bignum = Bignum;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string line;
      CSVline csv = new CSVline();

      using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"filepath of csv") )
      {
        try
        {
          while ( ( line = sr.ReadLine() ) != null )
          {
            var values = line.Split(',');
            csv.Country.Add(values[1]);
          }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
          Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read {0}", ex);
        }

      }
    }
  }

}
```

This results in the error "The file could not be read System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" this is from the line "csv.Country.Add(values[1]);"

Comment: Could you add to your answer text the first 4 lines of your CSV, please?

Comment: @OlivierRogier There are the first for lines of the CSV.

Comment: You don't want a list of countries in your one struct. Instead you want a struct with one country (etc), and then a list of those structs.

Comment: There is no header?

Comment: The country is the first part of the string, so `values[0]` - the index is 0-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made your struct wrong, you shouldn't add a list inside your struct, each record of your struct should contain entries for just one country, then you can make a list of your struct like this:

```
public struct CSVline
{
public string Country;
public string Continent;
public int popualtion;
public int landmass;
public long Bignum;

public CSVline(string Country, string Continent, int popualtion, int landmass, long Bignum)
{
    this.Country = Country;
    this.Continent = Continent;
    this.popualtion = popualtion;
    this.landmass = landmass;
    this.Bignum = Bignum;
}


}
```

then you can do this:

```
    string line;
    var csv  = new List<CSVline>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"filepath of csv"))
    {
        try
        { 
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var values = line.Split(',');
                csv.Add(new CSVline(values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3],values[4]));



            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read {0}", ex);
        }
      }
```

Comment: You can add a check before the `csv.Add` to test if `Lenght == 5` else show a message error "bad format" and skip the line. And for the exception it may be `ex.Message` instead of `ex`. If the CSV file has a header, skip the first line.